# MySQL: Combining multiple values from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm making an interactive festival programme, and decided to keep the information in a database for easy display and search. Each show can be presented in three different languages, they can have one or more show times, and many different artists. So there are many things that can be different from show to show, which is why it would be best to have some of the information in their own tables. The artists especially, as the same artist could appear at many different shows and the number of artists for each show varies.

So far I have one main table with the show title, its description, show time, ticket price etc. I want the artists to have their own table, and reference the artists by their ID and attach them to the different shows as the PHP script loops through the main table.

1. How can I reference an artist ID from another table in the main table?
2. What would a good query that fetches the artists from their table look like?

Tables (preliminary plan):

**Main table**

```
id | show title | show date | description | performers
------------------------------------------------------
1  | Beethoven  | 13.4.2013 | A classic   | 1,35,22,3
2  | Mozart     | 14.4.2013 | Fantastic   | 9,4,66

etc..
```

**Artist table**

```
id | name  | instrument |
-------------------------
1  | Steve | Violin     |
2  | Alex  | Piano      |

etc...
```

The numbers in the "performers" column would correspond to the ID's in the artist-table. Not sure that this is the right way to reference them, though. The PHP script would then combine both and output a complete show item.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 2. Once you show your tables, make sure you have the fields you need to join the information (foreign keys)

Comment: Can there be different artists for different show times on the same day?

Comment: @Revent There is generally only one show per day. If there's two, it's a repeat of the earlier show. There could be changes in artists though! I'm looking to write a very flexible database that would work for many show configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would set up the data schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `artists` (
  `artist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `artist_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `instrument` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`artist_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE `Shows` (
  `show_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `show_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `language` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`show_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE `show_times` (
  `show_time_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `show_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `show_date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `show_time` time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`show_time_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE `show_time_artist_lookup` (
  `show_time_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `artist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`show_time_id`,`artist_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

This will allow you to use the same show information for different dates/times. The artists would then be tied to show times using the lookup table.

Edit:
Actually for the languages, since you have a small set of options, you could use binary math and store a tiny number in a single field. For example:

1 = English
2 = Italian
4 = German

You can store a TinyINT value (change the schema to this)

```
`language` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '1',
```

with any one of the three values, or a combination. For example if the show is offered in English and Italian, you would store the value 3. For all three languages it would be 7. Then when you pull your show data, you use whatever programming language to do a binary math comparison to decode it. Here is a page explaining how to do it in PHP: http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/bitwise.htm

Comment: If you wanted to you could break out the languages as well. With this schema you could have up to 3 entries for the same show, one per language.

Comment: Thanks, this looks fantastic! You and the other answers helped me a lot. For the languages I might just do three columns for each entry that has translatable data, since the number of languages is set in stone. Then the PHP script can pick out the right language column as it loops.

Comment: Hi again! I've tried a while, and I can't get the query to work. It joins the tables, I've added foreign keys where applicable, but the queries won't return any rows, even when I select *. I also changed all from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have `show` table with two columns: show_id, name. Where show_id is a PRIMARY KEY.
Lets assume you have `artist` table with two columns: artist_id, name. Where artist_id is a PRIMARY KEY.

What you need is called m:n relation, meaning one artist can be assigned to many shows and one show can have many artists. To do it you need to create a new table to store this relations.
Let's name it `show_artist` with two columns show_id, artist_id. Both columns will be PRIMARY KEY. Each row in this table will store one relation between one particular artist (defined by artist_id) and one show (defined by show_id)

if you know show_id, you can fetch all artist names in this show using this query:

```
SELECT name FROM show_artist JOIN artist USING (artist_id) WHERE show_id = [YOUR SHOW ID]
```

Comment: Thanks, very valuable info. This complements @Revents answer nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do the queries you are asking about is using what's usually called a "join" table.  This is an extra table in which you list the show id in one column and the artist id in another column.  For example:

**MainArtists table**

```
showid | artistid
-------------------
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 1
```

In this join table, both Steve and Alex are in the Beethoven show, but only Steve is in the Mozart show.

To get them out, you use the join command in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM Main
INNER JOIN MainArtists ON ShowArtists.showid = Main.id
INNER JOIN Artists ON Artists.id = MainArtists.artistid
```

This query would get you one row per artist per show.  If you wanted only a list of artists from show #1, you would add "WHERE main.id = 1" at the end, and so forth.

It is good practice to assign the id columns in Main and Artists as primary keys, and showid and artistid columns in MainArtists as foreign keys that link back to their respective tables.  There are many resources on the internet concerning joins and foreign/primary key relationships, so searching for those terms should help you as you go along.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful and complements what @Revent suggested.